# SSL_write returns SSL_ERR_SYSCALL while ERR_get_error and errno are both 0

Tags: c++, c, debugging, openssl

I'm facing a strange problem and the openssl error handling and documentation didn't help.
I use `SSL_dup`(after an `SSL_new`), `SSL_set_fd` and `SSL_connect` to start an SSL session.
But then when I use `SSL_write`, it returns 0. The openssl [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_write.html) says to check `SSL_get_error`. I did and it gave me `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL`. 
The [docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_get_error.html) also suggest checking error queue and errno. But they are both zero. Now things get intereseting. The documentation says

> SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL
>
> Some non-recoverable, fatal I/O error occurred. The OpenSSL error queue may contain more information on the error. For socket I/O on Unix systems, consult errno for details. If this error occurs then no further I/O operations should be performed on the connection and SSL_shutdown() must not be called.
>
> This value can also be returned for other errors, check the error queue for details.

It says it's non recoverable but when I call `SSL_write` again with the same parameters, it works successfully. But obviously I cannot leave the code like this ignoring the error code of the first call. Here is what I have tried to troubleshoot the problem from what I found on the Internet.

- I used `select` to wait for the underlying socket to become ready for writing.
- I checked for EOF on `SSL_get_rbio` and `SSL_get_wbio`. `BIO_eof` returns 0 for both of them.
- I tried `SSL_do_handshake` before calling `SSL_write`. This may be unnecessary anyway because according the [openssl source](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/30a4cda5e0c67b4e77da4f21b7c5f27991d3367a/ssl/ssl_lib.c#L1710) it is called when I do `SSL_connect`.
- I tried checking `SSL_is_init_finished` but it returns 1 and doesn't indicate an issue here.

My openssl version is 1.1.1 and I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.3

Why does this problem occurs? How can I find the reason and fix it?

Comment: Firstly, you need to extract and provide a [mcve]. This helps you diagnose the problem yourself and without it your question is off-topic.

Comment: @D.Jones, It looks like a very nice problem to solve. I'm just dying to see your minimal reproducible example :)

Comment: Older versions of OpenSSL used to have there this text "If the error queue is empty (i.e. `ERR_get_error()` returns 0), `ret` can be used to find out more about the error: If `ret == 0`, an `EOF` was observed that violates the protocol". I don't know if that behaviour changed, or someone just reworded the manpage "for clarity" ;-)

Comment: This is the [commit](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/beacb0f) which changed it.

Comment: Thanks for your interest in my question. While I was working on creating a minimal reproducible example, fortunately I found the bug. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question as I found what the issue was. It wasn't even an OpenSSL problem.

First, see this GitHub issue: [SSL_write() returns SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL when size is 0](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/6308)

My code looks like this,

```
SSL_write(ssl, foo(), var);
```

`foo` creates a payload and returns a `const char *` and `var` is the length of that data. The thing is, they are actually member function and member variable of a C++ class and `var` is set by `foo`. According to C++ standard, evaluation order of function arguments are not specified. From 5.2.2,

> The order of evaluation of arguments is unspecified. All side effects
>   of argument expression evaluations take effect before the function is
>   entered.

So, it is possible for the third parameter(`var`) to be evaluated before the second parameter(`foo()`). Indeed, it is what was happening according to the assembly output of the program. Below is an example.

```
class myclass {
  public:
    int l;
    const char *foo(){
      l = 10;
      return "mystring";
    }
};

int main()
{
  SSL *ssl;
  myclass instance;
  SSL_write(ssl, instance.foo(), instance.l);
}
```

and the assembly,

```
_ZN7myclass3fooEv:
.LFB1778:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    $10, (%rax)
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1778:
    .size   _ZN7myclass3fooEv, .-_ZN7myclass3fooEv
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1779:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    pushq   %rbx
    subq    $40, %rsp
    .cfi_offset 3, -24
    movq    %fs:40, %rax
    movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movl    -36(%rbp), %ebx
    leaq    -36(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZN7myclass3fooEv
    movq    %rax, %rcx
    movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movl    %ebx, %edx ; rdx is the third parameter, var. ebx was set before the foo() call
    movq    %rcx, %rsi ; rsi is the second parameter, return value of foo()
    movq    %rax, %rdi ; rdi is the first parameter, ssl
    call    SSL_write@PLT
    movl    $0, %eax
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rdx
```

After `SSL_write`, `foo()` is guaranteed to be executed and `var` is set to the correct value, that's why the `SSL_write` was working the second time I suppose.
Moreover, the docs for `SSL_write` says

> You should not call SSL_write() with num=0, it will return an error. SSL_write_ex() can be called with num=0, but will not send application data to the peer.